# How make dynamic columns in groupped ListItem in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I've groupped ListItems. How can I make like:
1. If there is one item in a group, Grid has 1 column with 100% width,
2. If there are two or even items in a group, Grid has 2 columns with 50% width,
3. If there are 3 or odd items in a group, Grid has 2 columns but the last(or the first) item in the Grid is one column with 100% width

This is Xamarin Forms

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentView
    {
        private ObservableCollection<GrouppedActionItemViewModel> groupped { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            groupped = new ObservableCollection<GrouppedActionItemViewModel>();
            GrouppedActionItemViewModel groupOne = new GrouppedActionItemViewModel()
            {
                LongName = "The first category",
                ShortName = "First"
            };

            GrouppedActionItemViewModel groupTwo = new GrouppedActionItemViewModel()
            {
                LongName = "The second category",
                ShortName = "Second"
            };

            groupOne.Add(new ActionItemViewModel() { Guid = "", Name = "One", Image = "", IsAction = true });
            groupOne.Add(new ActionItemViewModel() { Guid = "", Name = "Two", Image = "", IsAction = true });
            groupOne.Add(new ActionItemViewModel() { Guid = "", Name = "Three", Image = "", IsAction = true });

            groupTwo.Add(new ActionItemViewModel() { Guid = "", Name = "One", Image = "", IsAction = true });
            groupTwo.Add(new ActionItemViewModel() { Guid = "", Name = "Two", Image = "", IsAction = true });

            groupped.Add(groupOne);
            groupped.Add(groupTwo);

            listView.GroupHeaderTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.FontSize = 40;
                label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("LongName"));
                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = label
                };
            });

            listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {
                // ???
                return new ViewCell
                {
                };
            });

            listView.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

            listView.ItemsSource = groupped;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not too much understanding what your want.If odd items , do you mean just want to show only one item? You can show a image to show what needs.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Sorry, my english is not goot. Image - [prntscr.com/oow7ub](http://prntscr.com/oow7ub)

Comment: Thanks for replying . I will check it ,if have solution will share here.